# Calling Firebase Function throws error - ERROR TypeError: Gb.functions is not a function

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I just recently started using Firebase Functions and hoping to get your assistance on the following error message that I am receiving after I run NG Build --Prod:

***ERROR TypeError: Gb.functions is not a function***

What is very strange about this error message is that I don't receive it on my localhost and can call the firebase function without error when running NG Serve --Open.

When I click on the 'Test' button, I am expecting for an email to be sent to my inbox.

Any insight you could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<button (click)="test()">Test</button>
```

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
admin.initializeApp();


let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'xxx',
        pass: 'xxx'
    }
});

exports.sendMail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {

        // getting dest email by query string
        const dest = req.query.dest;

        const mailOptions = {
            from: 'xxx', // Something like: Jane Doe <janedoe@gmail.com>
            to: 'xxx',
            subject: 'test', // email subject
            html: `test` 
        };

        // returning result
        return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
            if (error) {
                return res.send(error.toString());
            }
            return res.send('Sended');
        });
    });
});
```

```js
test() {
    const helloWorld = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('sendMail');
    helloWorld().then((result) => {
      console.log(result.data.output);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(`error occurred`);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you use angular fire?

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question lol but how would I use Angular Fire in this instance?

Comment: You mentioned Angular, well I guess I should've asked, are you using AngularJS or Angular 2+ ?